# refresh a fragment in a tab in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have one tab, where the user puts in some Information and can read them in the other. Therefore I need to refresh the second tab, but I have no clue how.
I already tried this code:

```
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

After the user saves some data, but I get a nullpointerException within the FragmentManager, when I use the fragment tag, I defined in the xml document.

Comment: Just a FYI, when you're posting questions, you can put all of your code in one block by putting each line indended by 4 spaces intstead of doing a new line surrounded in ` for every line.  Be sure to put an empty line between your text and the code block

Comment: Still no one got a solution? I don't find any mistake in my code... :(